# Ruby unescape HTML string

Tags: ruby, html-escape-characters

Any idea how I can unescape the following string in Ruby?

```
C&#x3a;&#x5c;inetpub&#x5c;wwwroot&#x5c;adminWeb
```

to

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\adminWeb
```

or to

```
C%3A%5Cinetpub%5Cwwwroot%5CadminWeb
```

Tried with `URI.decode` with no success.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`CGI` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/index.html) is one option:

```
require 'cgi'

CGI.unescapeHTML('C&#x3a;&#x5c;inetpub&#x5c;wwwroot&#x5c;adminWeb')
# => "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\adminWeb"
```

Answer (score 6):

One more variant is [HTMLEntities](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities)

```
HTMLEntities.new.decode "C&#x3a;&#x5c;inetpub&#x5c;wwwroot&#x5c;adminWeb"             
# => "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\adminWeb"
```

I prefer to use it because it deals with rare cases as`&aring;` and `&mdash;` which `CGI.unescapeHTML` does not

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using the standard lib's [URI module](http://devdocs.io/ruby/uri/escape#method-i-unescape):

```
require 'uri'
URI.unescape "C%3A%5Cinetpub%5Cwwwroot%5CadminWeb" # => "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\adminWeb"
```

**EDIT**
This is answer is obsolete. Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65423458/ruby-2-7-says-uri-escape-is-obsolete-what-replaces-it).

Comment: URI.unescape (now obsolete) will decode %-escaped characters in URLs. That's different from decoding HTML entities (&...;).