# Ruby 2.7 says URI.escape is obsolete, what replaces it?

Tags: ruby

I'm using `URI.encode` to generate HTML data URLs:

```rb
visit "data:text/html,#{URI::encode(html)}"
```

After upgrading to Ruby 2.7.1, interpreter started warning:

```
warning: URI.escape is obsolete
```

Recommended replacements of this are `CGI.escape` and `URI.encode_www_form_component`. However, they're not doing same thing:

```
2.7.1 :007 > URI.escape '<html>this and that</html>'
(irb):7: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
 => "%3Chtml%3Ethis%20and%20that%3C/html%3E"
2.7.1 :008 > CGI.escape '<html>this and that</html>'
 => "%3Chtml%3Ethis+and+that%3C%2Fhtml%3E"
2.7.1 :009 > URI.encode_www_form_component '<html>this and that</html>'
 => "%3Chtml%3Ethis+and+that%3C%2Fhtml%3E"
```

Result of these slight encoding differences - html page where spaces are replaced by `+`. My question is - what's a good replacement of `URI.encode` for this use case?

Comment: Take a look at [`ERB::Util.url_encode`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB/Util.html#url_encode-method) – it encodes space as `%20` and also encodes `/` as `%2F` (which is perfectly fine)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no official RFC 3986-compliant URI escaper in the Ruby standard library today.

See [Why is URI.escape() marked as obsolete and where is this REGEXP::UNSAFE constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274838/why-is-uri-escape-marked-as-obsolete-and-where-is-this-regexpunsafe-constant) for background.

There are several methods that have various issues with them as you have discovered and pointed out in the comment:

- They produce deprecation warnings
- They do not claim standards compliance
- They are not escaping in accordance with RFC 3986
- They are implemented in tangentially related libraries

Comment: This seems an odd omission from the ruby stdlib

Answer (score 53):

There is actually a drop in replacement.

```
s = '<html>this and that</html>'    
p = URI::Parser.new
p.escape(s)
=> "%3Chtml%3Ethis%20and%20that%3C/html%3E"
```

Docs: [https://docs.w3cub.com/ruby~3/uri/rfc2396_parser](https://docs.w3cub.com/ruby%7E3/uri/rfc2396_parser)

Found this through a comment under this article
https://docs.knapsackpro.com/2020/uri-escape-is-obsolete-percent-encoding-your-query-string

Also tested this against some other strings in my setup, this also seems to retain commas the same way `URI.escape` does, in contrast to `ERB::Util.url_encode`.

**NOTE:**
As this answer became so popular now, it's probably worth to mention that you **should not blindly** change your code to use `URI::Parser` unless you are certain your project doesn't need a standards compliant encoder. As `URI.escape` was actually **deprecated for a reason**. So before simply switching to `URI::Parser` make sure you have read and understood https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059657/6376353

Comment: Using `URI::Parser#escape` is _exactly_ the same as using `URI::escape`, except without the warning.  And that's fine, if that's what you want, but it's important to realize that this is not a different solution.  If you look at the source code, `URI::escape` calls `URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.escape`, and `URI::DEFAULT_PARSER` is an instance of `URI::Parser`.

Answer (score 6):

From [Apidock.com](https://apidock.com/ruby/ERB/Util/url_encode)

```
require "erb"
include ERB::Util

puts url_encode("Programming Ruby:  The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide")
```

Generates

> Programming%20Ruby%3A%20%20The%20Pragmatic%20Programmer%27s%20Guide

Comment: Or without including the module: `ERB::Util.url_encode("<=>")`

Answer (score 4):

This replaces URI.escape behaviour for links:

**Ruby 2.x**:

```
URI.escape("http://example.com/?a=\11\15")
# => "http://example.com/?a=%09%0D"
```

**Ruby 3.x**:

```
URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.escape("http://example.com/?a=\11\15")
# => "http://example.com/?a=%09%0D"
```

Answer (score 2):

One alternative, in newer Rubies, is `URI.encode_uri_component`. But it replaces `[]`, too.

```
# ruby 2.2, the original URI.encode:
irb(main):007:0> URI.encode "test_query[]=value with spaces"
=> "test_query[]=value%20with%20spaces"
# NOTE: ruby 2.2 doesn't have URI.encode_uri_component

# ruby 3.2.1

# use this to encode a single component (the stuff before and after "=")
irb(main):009:0> URI.encode_uri_component "test_query[]=value with spaces"
=> "test_query%5B%5D%3Dvalue%20with%20spaces"

irb(main):014:0> CGI.escapeURIComponent "test_query[]=value with spaces"
=> "test_query%5B%5D%3Dvalue%20with%20spaces"

# NOTE: different format/ RFC
irb(main):010:0> URI.encode_www_form_component "test_query[]=value with spaces"
=> "test_query%5B%5D%3Dvalue+with+spaces"

# NOTE: different format/ RFC
irb(main):013:0> CGI.escape "test_query[]=value with spaces"
=> "test_query%5B%5D%3Dvalue+with+spaces"
```

As you can see, none of the above is the direct replacement for `URI.encode`.
But the other ones are correct in specific scenarios.

Replacing `[]` is correct. Replacing `=` is not for this use case.
So you should do something like `["test_query[]", "value with spaces"].map {|x| URI.escape_uri_component(x) }.join("=")` if you want to construct query parameters manually, for example.

I.e. the "component" in the name is the keyword here.

Relevant Ruby issue: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17309

Comment: `URI.encode_uri_component` doesn't appear to be a valid method? At least, not in ruby 2.7.7

Comment: @nzifnab Yes, see the first 4 lines in the example code.

Answer (score 2):

for now you we can use -

```
URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.escape("URL")
```